# Auto Logon Windows XP

Tags: .net, windows-xp

I need to setup auto logon to an XP machine, I cannot use the standrad method by setting the registry entries or using Tweak as the password can be viewed as plain text. For this project the password must be stored as encrypted on the PC. I have looked into modifying GINA.DLL and calling this through a .NET Application running as a service. Does anyone have any ideas on how to progress this?

All comments would be grateful

Answer (score 1):

I did work on a proxy GINA for one of our projects for automatic logon.  The project was done in C++ ( infact all the calls that you can make at that level is pure c style calls )

To my understanding, you will not be able to use managed ( .NET ) code for GINA.
GINA is loaded by Winlogon and is pretty early phase than loading services.

The custom Gina can be loaded using GinaDLL registry key under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool in SysInternals as Autologon.exe can help with autologon.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this can still be viewed by programs like LSASecretsView, I need something more secure than this?